# Userform - Redirect focus on textbox after MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel, userform, setfocus

I hope this is not that stupid, but I really did not find a post that was working for me.
**Situation:** I want someone to put a date into a textbox in a Userform.
**ErrorHandler:** I wanted to have a very simple solution if the user doesn't enter the right format. (EB_Start.Activate and EB_Start.SetFocus are NOT working at all)

*For this I got:*

```
Private Sub EB_Ende_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   On Error GoTo Error_Handler
   Me.EB_Ende = CDate(Me.EB_Ende)                                                  
      Error_Handler:
      EB_Start.Activate
      EB_Start.SetFocus
MsgBox ("Please enter a valid date"), , "Datum"
End Sub
```

**Problem:**
My Question is now, how do I redirect the focus on the textbox(EB_Ende)
The current reaction is, after the user presses Enter after the MsgBox showed up, It continued to the next textbox, but I want the user to be forced to reenter a valid date in the textbox.

If someone could help me out with this, or redirect me to a Post or link that will answer my question I would really appreciate it.

Best regards,
Lutscha

This is the whole UserForm
[image: Sry it is in german]

Comment: Why are you not exiting the sub between before the error handler starts?  And, which version of Excel are you using?  In Office 2013, for example, UserForm Textboxes don't *have* an `Activate` method, so you'd get a second error on `EB_Start.Activate`...  Try commenting that line out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting focus in `BeforeUpdate` event won't work - it is too soon. It is fired before focus is moved to the next control. Better approach is to handle `Exit` event and cancel it when needed:

```
Private Sub EB_Ende_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  On Error GoTo Error_Handler
  EB_Ende = CDate(EB_Ende)
  Exit Sub   '<-- exit sub when there is no error
Error_Handler:
  Cancel = True
  MsgBox ("Please enter a valid date"), , "Datum"
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation.
Did not know that the BeforeUpdate is too early. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues with your code (e.g. not exiting before the error handler, and do you want to use `Cancel=msoTrue` to cancel the text entry to `EB_Ende` when you get an error?) so you could try this:

```
Private Sub EB_Ende_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   On Error GoTo Error_Handler
   Me.EB_Ende = CDate(Me.EB_Ende)                                                  
   Exit Sub
Error_Handler:
    EB_Start.SetFocus
    MsgBox ("Please enter a valid date"), , "Datum"
End Sub
```

Or, you could skip the error-hander entirely:

```
Private Sub EB_Ende_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If IsDate(Me.EB_Ende) Then
        Me.EB_Ende = CDate(Me.EB_Ende)                                                  
    Else
        Cancel = msoTrue
        EB_Start.SetFocus
        MsgBox ("Please enter a valid date"), , "Datum"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, I don't understand your second option entirely but I will look it up because it looks really good.

Comment: All it does is use the built-in `IsDate` to decide if the value Is a Date, instead of waiting for `CDate` to error

Answer (score 1):

The funny thing is, you used the answer as a tag on your question:

```
Me.EB_Ende.SetFocus
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/textbox-control-setfocus-method-enterfieldbehavior-hideselection-multiline-value) is more information on `SetFocus`.

Something else that might help...  you can change the default order that objects are "tabbed" through.  (ie., what cell should get focus after you press enter or tab in the current control:

[image: img]

Comment: Appereantly this is not working either.
If I klick the Msgbox Window away with enter, it still redirects me to the next Tab though I would like to redirect him to the Tab before.
The Me.EB_Ende.SetFocus does not much more than the same without Me.

Comment: Did you try both of my suggestions?

Comment: Kind of. I looked up the default order, but there is no option to repeat the same tab, if necessary. So I like that I know now this is possible, but I doen't really help me with the problem to redirect the user to the same box he/she just entered something wrong.
-> If it is imortant, I try to do all this in a Multipage

Answer (score 0):

**worked perfect**

Private Sub txtSalary_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

If Not IsNumeric(txtSalary) Then
MsgBox "Please, only numbers!", vbRetryCancel
Cancel = True
txtSalary = ""
End If

If IsNumeric(txtSalary) Then
txtSalary = Format(txtSalary, "$#,##0.00")
End If
End Sub